# export query from access to mssql seen as normal table in MSSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am in the process of converting an application from MS Access 2016 to a web base app.  I use linked tables in Access but the web app has to access the SQL Server directly. I have several queries I need to use so I exported the query to MSSQL and it works. But in MSSQL shows it as a normal table.

It doesn't show joins or even the original table names the fields are associated with.

Is this normal? I didn't want to have to use access to modify the query table, or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I looked like it exported the query as a table but no data shows up. If you edit the table all the fields are there.

Answer (score 0):

I looked like it exported the query as a table but no data shows up. If you edit the table all the fields are there though. The export should have given an error as it is unusable.